# CasperJS fill input occasionally fails

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Has anyone ever run into the problem of CasperJS not filling in the inputs completely? Particularly with #fill or #sendKeys.

When I try to verify the inputs later with #assertField (or some other #test.assert):

1. Sometimes it works fine and the test passes
2. Sometimes the input field is partially filled
3. Sometimes the input field isn't filled at all

I suspect it may occasionally be executing the commands too quickly so it moves onto the next command before completely filling in an input (or filling it in at all). I've tried adding a wait after the fill inputs and that seems to work, but it somehow seems hacky, and I'm still not 100% sure that won't fail.

Any ideas why this might be happening or some solutions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: That is strange. Is the page doing any or even extensive validation/sanitation on the inputs?

Comment: `fill` and its variants are completely synchronous. So this shouldn't happen. Please show your code. Maybe you're using it wrong.